# Guardar cryto en una cuenta para luego enviar a otras con solidity

Tags: transacciones, solidity

estoy creando una Dapp para practicar solidity en donde la gente compra la moneda ERC20 de mi contrato inteligente para mantenerlo como saldo de su cuenta, para pagar a otros usuarios de la Dapp y en el mismo pago que hace el usuario enviar un porcentaje a una cuenta propia para yo ganar por comision, pero que el usuario tambien pueda decidir si cambia el token por una crytomoneda para enviarlo a su cuenta, mis preguntas son:

**1)** como se hace en solidity para que la gente pueda comprar la moneda ERC20
y luego guardarlo en mi Dapp, y luego el usuario pueda pagar a otros y yo quedarme la
comision?

Espero que alguien sepa del tema, gracias.

**Este es el código del token ERC20:**

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract token {

    string public name; /// funcion para obtener el nombre del token
    string public symbol; /// funcion para obtener el simbolo del token
    uint8 public decimals; /// funcion para obtener el numero de decimales del token
    uint256 public totalSupply; /// funcion para obtener la cantidad total de tokens
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf; /// funcion para obtener el balance de una direccion
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance; /// funcion para obtener el permiso de una direccion y pretar los token

    event Transfer(address indexed desde, address indexed para, uint256 valor); /// evento para notificar cuando una transferencia es hecha
    event Approval(address indexed propiedario, address indexed autorizado, uint256 valor); /// evento para notificar que una persona autoriza una transferencia

    constructor(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint8 _decimals, uint256 _totalSupply) public {
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        decimals = _decimals;
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }

    function transfer(address para, uint256 valor) public returns (bool) { /// funcion para transferir tokens
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= valor, "Fondos insuficientes."); /// verifica que el balance del emisor sea mayor o igual al valor a transferir
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= valor; /// resta el valor a transferir del balance del emisor
        balanceOf[para] += valor; /// suma el valor a transferir al balance del destinatario
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, para, valor); /// notifica que una transferencia fue hecha
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address gastador, uint256 valor) public returns (bool) { 
        require( balanceOf[msg.sender] >= valor, "Fondos Insuficientes." ); /// verifica que el balance del emisor sea mayor o igual al valor a transferir
        allowance[msg.sender][gastador] = valor; /// permite que una persona gastador pueda transferir tokens
        emit Approval(msg.sender, gastador, valor); /// notifica que una persona autorizo una transferencia
        return true; 
    }

    function transferFrom(address desde, address para, uint256 valor) public returns (bool) {
        require(allowance[desde][msg.sender] >= valor, "No tienes permiso para transferir."); /// verifica que el permiso del emisor sea mayor o igual al valor a transferir
        require(balanceOf[desde] >= valor, "Fondos insuficientes."); /// verifica que el balance del emisor sea mayor o igual al valor a transferir

        balanceOf[desde] -= valor; /// resta el valor a transferir del balance del emisor
        allowance[desde][msg.sender] -= valor; /// resta el valor a transferir del permiso del emisor
        balanceOf[para] += valor; /// suma el valor a transferir al balance del destinatario

        emit Transfer(desde, para, valor); /// notifica que una transferencia fue hecha
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Este es el código para crear una tarea:**

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract tarea {

    struct datosTarea {
        uint256 id;
        string titulo;
        string descripcion;
        uint256 fecha;
    }

    uint256 public contador;
    mapping( uint256 => datosTarea ) public ListaTareas;

    function crearTarea( string memory _titulo, string memory _descripcion ) public returns(bool){
        ListaTareas[contador] = datosTarea(contador,_titulo,_descripcion,block.timestamp);
        contador++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**este es mi html y javascript para crear, guardar y sacar las tareas de la blockchain simulada que me ofrece ganache:**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>blockchain</title>
<script src="web3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="cuenta">Cuenta: No Conectado</h2>
<h2 id="ntares">N Tareas: No Conectado</h2>
<h2 id="nbalance">ETH: No Conectado</h2>
<div style="border:1px solid black;margin:10px;">
    <input id="a" type="text" placeholder="titulo"></input>
    <input id="b" type="text" placeholder="descripcion"></input>
    <input onclick="window.guardarr();" id="c" type="button" value="Guardar en blockchain"></input>
</div>
<script>
    
    var cuentas;
    var web3;
    var LaCuenta;
    var contratoJson;
    var contrato;
    
    window.guardarr = function() {
        guarda();
    };  
    
    async function guarda() {
            var titulo = document.getElementById('a').value;
            var descripcion = document.getElementById('b').value;
            
            var dd = await contrato.methods.crearTarea(titulo,descripcion).send({from:LaCuenta});
            window.location.reload();
    }   
    
    
    async function cargarContrato() {
        const res = await fetch('tarea.json');
        contratoJson = await res.json();
        const idRed = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        contrato = new web3.eth.Contract(contratoJson.abi,contratoJson.networks[idRed].address); 
        console.log(contrato);
    }
    
    async function conectar () {
        if( window.ethereum ) {
            try{
            /// conectar metamask
            cuentas = await window.ethereum.request({'method': 'eth_requestAccounts'});
            
            /// obtener el objeto web3
            web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
            console.log(web3);
            
            /// obtener la cuenta
            var LaCuentaTemp = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
            LaCuenta = LaCuentaTemp[0];
            
            document.getElementById('cuenta').innerText = 'Cuenta: '+LaCuenta;
            
            await cargarContrato();

            const totalTareas = await contrato.methods.contador().call();
            document.getElementById('ntares').innerText = 'N Tareas: '+totalTareas;
            
            const balancee = await web3.eth.getBalance(LaCuenta);
            document.getElementById('nbalance').innerText = 'ETH: '+balancee;
            
            var cont = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < totalTareas; i++) {
                const Tareas = await contrato.methods.ListaTareas(i).call();
                var idTarea = Tareas[0];
                var TituloTarea = Tareas[1];
                var DescripcionTarea = Tareas[2];
                var FechaTarea = Tareas[3];
                
                cont += '<div style="border:1px solid gray;">';
                    cont += '<h3>'+TituloTarea+' - id: '+idTarea+'</h3>';   
                    cont += '<p>'+DescripcionTarea+'</p>';
                    cont += '<p>'+(new Date(FechaTarea*1000).toLocaleString())+'</p>';
                cont += '</div>';
                
            }
            document.body.innerHTML += cont;
            
            }catch(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        }else{
            alert("Instala primero metamask.");
        }
    }
    conectar();
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Realmente espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, soy nuevo en stackoverflow, vine aquí con la esperanza de recibir un poco de ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Muchas preguntas en una no van con el formato.. pedir tutoriales tampoco va con nuestro formato.. Revisa tu pregunta, si no va a terminar cerrada...

Comment: Que me recomiendan tampoco es una pregunta valida para este sitio. Aca se contestan preguntas concretas sobre problemas de programacion... No se recomiendan cosas, ni es un foro de discusion...

Comment: Ahora por lo menos, es una pregunta valida... Lo que no se, es si tiene respuesta.. saludos...

Comment: llego un poco tarde, aquí tienes una lista completa que te puede ayudar incluso más de lo que tienes pensado: [https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb12FJb5OYxiBNYFEmXyfa7ox-Rkowxof](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb12FJb5OYxiBNYFEmXyfa7ox-Rkowxof) No solo la lista, te recomiendo el canal entero, a mi me ha salvado la vida.